# How to get Multiple Result Set in Entity Framework using Linq with C#?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

In my stored procedure, I have two select statement based on two result set i would like to get the details using linq with c# code.

Below is my Stored Procedure :

```
Create Proc SP_GetResult
As
Begin
    Select Id,Name from EmployeeTable;
    Select ContactNo,DateOfBirth from Customer;
End
```

I tried below code to call Stored Procedure using Linq :

```
Public void SelectValues()
{
    using (Entities1 entity = new Entities1())
    {
       var list = entity.SP_GetResult

       foreach (var test in list)
       {
          var test12123 = test;
       }
    }
}
```

I can get only EmployeeTable details. But, I can't get Customer table details.

How to do it ?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

It's achievable, there is a great explanation in MSDN . Check this article, it shows two ways to achieve it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx

For Your requirements use approach 2 (Multiple Result Sets with Configured in EDMX).

Once You do this You can use those results with Linq without a problem.For example

```
Public void SelectValues()
{
    using (Entities1 entity = new Entities1())
    {
       var Employees = entity.SP_GetResult;
       var Customers = Employees.GetNextResult<Customer>();
       // do your stuff
    }
}
```

To 'join' those 2 collection You can use a Tuple Collection

```
Tuple<EmployeeTable, Customer>
```

Since the above approach works only for .NET 4.5 and higher, you can use the first approach from the article. It also suits you. You can use linq there. Look at my example:

```
public List<EmployeeTable> GetEmployees()
{
using(var ctx = new myEntities())
{
    var cmd = ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[SP_GetResult]";

    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
    //reader.NextResult(); <- uncomment this to get second result(Customer)
    var employees = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db) 
        .ObjectContext 
        .Translate<EmployeeTable>(reader, "EmployeeTable", MergeOption.AppendOnly); 
    return employees;
}
```

Now You can use linq like:

```
var boss = GetEmployees().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "BossName");
```

Alternative:

Actually to do such simple queries You don't need to have it in one sp. You don't even need store procedures for this. Having only EF You can get it like this:

```
using (var ctx = new myEntities())
{
    var employyes = from x in ctx.EmployeeTable select new
    {
        id = x.Id,
        name = x.Name
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw that link, But i am looking for using linq to achieve this task. How can do it. In that link they are using BloggingContext() to achieve the problem. If there is any way then please help me to do it.

Comment: Ok, but first - I assume You use database first, not model first right ?

Comment: Yes exactly. I would like to use database first based on my above example code.

Comment: can you please help to solve this issue. I refered some articles they said I need to upgrade my Entity Version. Because I am using Entity version 4.0.0.0.

Comment: I tried below your posted code but I am getting null values in Customers.  var Customers = Employees.GetNextResult<Customer>();

Comment: what is customer how i need to pass the customer class with parameters.

Comment: Don't use this approach we spoke that it require .NET 4.5 and EF 5 I believe. Use second one (EDIT 2)

Comment: I tried to use second one(Edit 2) I'm getting error while calling db.DataBase.

Comment: 'EntityFrameWork_test.PlanGenEntities' does not contain a definition for 'Databse' and no extension method 'Databse' accepting a first argument of type 'EntityFrameWork_test.PlanGenEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Really ? There is a INTELLISENSE - use it. There was a typo. It should be ctx.Database

Comment: Getting same error 1:
'EntityFrameWork_test.PlanGenEntities' does not contain a definition for 'Database' and no extension method 'Database' accepting a first argument of type 'EntityFrameWork_test.PlanGenEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

error 2:
The name 'db' does not exist in the current context

error 3:
The type or namespace name 'IObjectContextAdapter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)